# How to check if a number is prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

I am having a problem with those numbers:

1) $2015^7 - 1$
2) $817^2 + 53^2$.

Especially when number is raised to a given power. My solution for the second point:  $817^2$ is the same as checking $817 \pmod 2 \equiv 1$, so using this for the second number: $53 \pmod 2 \equiv 1$ means that both numbers are $\pmod 1$ and it means that if we add both numbers $\pmod 1$ we receive a $\pmod 0$ number so it isn't a prime number. Am I doing this correctly? Could you give me any tips for first point and if this is wrong for the second as well.

Comment: Please explain your question as well as your working more **clearly**..

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense as written. Please reread and edit it to better explain what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I won't comment on your technique, rather an obvious solution that means I can look at these and tell you they aren't prime. An odd number multiplied by an odd number is always odd - namely a power of an odd number is odd - so $2015^7$ is odd and so $2015^7 - 1$ is even, and thus not prime (2 is the only even prime).

Similarly 817^2 and 53^2 are both odd, hence there sum is even and not prime.

Comment: I am using same technique as on this video: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/random-algorithms-probability/v/fermat-primality-test-prime-adventure-part-10

Comment: Ah, I think I see your mistake. The video that you linked to is a prime test, but it tests the exponent. So for $2015^{7-1}=1$ mod $7$ since 7 is prime and is coprime to 2015 - this doesn't tell us anything about $2015^7-1$. 

The primality test goes like this: suppose we want to see if x is prime, we randomly choose an a less than and coprime to x, and check that $a^{x-1}=1$ mod $x$ - if this congruence fails, we know x is not prime, otherwise we keep checking different values for a. The more a's we check, the better the chance that x is prime however certain numbers (pt.1)

Comment: Actually pass the test for all values of a, but aren't prime - the so called carmicheal numbers.

Rereading your question and trying to understand what you are getting at, it seems like you've done the same as me for your second part. Whereas I said the squares are both odd and so the sum is even, you've included congruence mod 2 (which is the same thing). You can apply the same logic to the first part and say $2015 =1$ mod $2$ so $2015^7=1$ mod $2$ so $2015^7-1=0$ mod $2$ and is not prime (in my answer I conclude that it's even). This test fails if the outcome is 1, and (pt.2)

Comment: *typo - This test fails if the outcome is 0, and this test is inconclusive if the outcome is 1. Basically you work out whether the number is even (and then report failure) or odd (report inconclusive) and thus I wouldn't recommend it. 

There is a way to use the fermat test with your question, but it is more nuanced; suppose we care about $2015^7-1$ - we can check $2^{(2015^7)-1} = 2 modulo 2015^7-1 which doesn't hold and hence isn't prime. If I've misinterpreted your question I apologize.